# Unable to use adb connect to enable wifi debugging

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I was debugging my xamarin android app on Phone1 over wifi by connecting to xxx:xxx:x:xxx:5556.
I tried to debug the app over wifi on Phone2 where only usb debugging was the straight forward option.
The commands I had used to connect to Phone2 are adb tcpip 5555, adb connect xxx:xxx:x:xxx:5555.
Now I am trying to connect back to Phone1:
adb connect xxx:xxx:x:xxx:5556 and it is giving me the error:
*"unable to connect xxx:xxx:x:xxx:5556:5555: cannot resolve host 'xxx.xxx.x.xxx:5556' and port 5555: No such host is known"*
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to run  `adb tcpip 5556` before running  `adb connect xxx:xxx:x:xxx:5556`

Answer (score 7):

Try this sequence of actions/commands in order to debug a USB host device over WiFi:

- stop USB host
- connect the USB debug cable

adb kill-server

adb tcpip 5555

adb devices

```
should show something like 
    List of devices attached
    99679a67        device
```

- find your device IP address and:

adb connect 192.168.14.94:5555

adb devices

```
should show something like 
    List of devices attached
    99679a67        device
    192.168.14.94:5555      device
```

- disconnect the USB debug cable

adb connect 192.168.14.94:5555

```
should show
    connected to 192.168.14.94:5555
```

adb devices

```
should show
    List of devices attached
    192.168.14.94:5555      device
```

- Start USB host on the device, if needed. ignore if you just need WiFi debug
- debug freely over WiFi

Comment: This comment was a lifesaver for me

Comment: It's worked for me. Just plug Usb cable and enable Usb debugging then unplug cable and enable wireless debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Google just updated the feature and officially support wifi debugging from Android 11 onwards. Follow these steps to setup your device to build and debug wirelessly using your wifi connection:

- On your Android 11 device, go to your Settings -> Tap on Advanced and go to the Developer options.
- Then tap on Wireless Debugging switch, and always allow wireless debugging for your personal wireless network in the popup dialog
- Then tap on the Wireless Debugging option and select “Pair device with pairing code” and it will give you a 6 digit code and IP address as you can see in the image
- There are many ways of doing pairing the phone to your computer. For the simplest one, inside Visual Studio, go to Tools -> SDK Command Prompt and type the IP address and port from your phone above into the terminaladb pair {ipaddress}:{port}.
- Then take the IP Address and port from the last screen and enter the following command adb connect {ipaddress}:{port}.

There’s a lot [more details in this article](https://prototypemakers.medium.com/wireless-build-debug-with-android-on-xamarin-is-officially-here-8110593b39cf?sk=9ae6ee95c3028232d21e699ee1f77163) Including limitations and a comparison with the iphone wireless debug feature